# Changing a string that contains numbers into a number then back into a string

Tags: javascript, query-string

I know this sounds a bit silly, but I need to find a way to change a querystrings value without any hardcoding.

So for example:

post_num=_443_1

I want to change it to the following:

post_num=_444_1

I've already gotten post_num's value, I just need to be able to change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the consistency of your format.

```
var numParts = str.split('_');
numParts[1]++;
var updated = '_' + numParts[1] + '_' + numParts[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic way to increment the first number in a string:

```
post_num.replace(/\d+/, function(n){return Number(n) + 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
post_num.replace(/^_(\d+)_(\d)$/, function(match, value, sufix) 
                                  { 
                                      return "_" + (parseInt(value) + 1) + "_" + sufix; 
                                  });
```

or almost the same:

```
post_num.replace(/^_(\d+)_(\d)$/, function(match, value, sufix) 
                                  { 
                                      return "_" + (+value + 1) + "_" + sufix; 
                                  });
```